# The cookie is not being sent in the browser

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

I have the following code that sends a request to the server by clicking a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Set Cookie Example</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="setCookie()">Set Cookie</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    function setCookie() {
      const cookieName = 'myCookie';
      const cookieValue = 'myValue';

      // set cookie with SameSite=None attribute and Secure flag (for HTTPS sites)
      document.cookie = `${cookieName}=${cookieValue}; SameSite=None; Secure; path=/`;

        axios.get('http://192.168.43.96:8000/api/post/', { withCredentials: true })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });

      // set cookie via document.cookie (fallback for older browsers)
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to set a cookie in this request(`myCookie=myValue`). However, this cookie is not being set in the browser(It is not present in the request headers).

[image: cookie didnt sent]

However, with `curl` with this code, it is sent perfectly fine.

```
const axios = require('axios');

// create a new Axios instance with default config
const instance = axios.create();

// set the cookie in the Axios instance config
instance.defaults.headers.common['Cookie'] = 'myCookie=myValue';

console.log(typeof instance)
// make a GET request using the Axios instance
instance.get('http://192.168.43.96:8000/api/post/')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

How can I also set the cookie in the browser? What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution:

Because I was making requests from the local host to the server, the cookie value was not being set.

**Solution:**

When I uploaded the client site on the server and essentially placed both the server and front-end in the same origin, everything worked fine.